# Button won't do anything Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, action, jbutton

I have looked over my code for a while and can not find why my button won't work. My "startButton" works when clicked on but my "helpButton" won't. When I click on the button it wont run the println code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class test extends JFrame{

    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;

    private ImageIcon bgi;
    private JLabel bgl;

    public static Rectangle gameSquare;


    private JButton startButton;
    private JButton helpButton;
    private final Action action = new SwingAction();


    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        test gui = new test ();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // when click x close program
        gui.setSize(902, 305);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setTitle("Solid Cloud Inc - Twitter Unfolower");
    }

    public test() throws MalformedURLException, IOException{

        bgi = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("tu.png"));
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://i1344.photobucket.com/albums/p656/SolidCloudInc/start_zpsf3781681.png"));
        //ImageIcon start = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("start.png"));
        startButton = new JButton("");
        startButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        startButton.setBounds(22, 186, 114, 50);


        getContentPane().add(startButton);

        BufferedImage img2 = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://i1344.photobucket.com/albums/p656/SolidCloudInc/help_zpsc4fad867.png"));
        final JButton helpButton = new JButton("");
        helpButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img2));
        helpButton.setBounds(192, 186, 114, 50);

        getContentPane().add(helpButton);

        bgl = new JLabel (bgi);
        bgl.setBounds(0, 0, 886, 272);
        getContentPane().add(bgl);

        Events e = new Events();
        startButton.addActionListener(e);
        helpButton.addActionListener(e);
    }

    public class Events implements ActionListener {


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getSource() == startButton) {
               label.setText("Searching");

               try {
                Unfollow();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
            else if (e.getSource() == helpButton){
                System.out.println("gottem");
            }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Does it work if you do `startButton.addActionListener(new Events());` and `helpButton.addActionListener(new Events());`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're shadowing the `JButton` variable `helpButton` in the `test` constructor, thereby comparing with an `null` reference in the `ActionListener`. Replace

```
JButton helpButton = new JButton("");
```

with

```
helpButton = new JButton("");
```

Aside: Java naming conventions show that classes start with *uppercase* letters such as `Test`.

Comment: @LukeWorthing: if his answer helped you, then up-vote it and also accept the answer.